# How can we add dynamic value when query string returns null value?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,IFNULL(state_table.state_name,"replace string") FROM doctor_table left join state_table on state=state.id
```

can we use sql select query instead of string _"replace_string"_?

Comment: It appears you want an outer join, but there's too little information.

Comment: sounds like left join and then coalesce

Comment: specify your question by clarify your intention and/or provide more background information.

Answer (score 0):

Try union all

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, state_table.state_name 
FROM doctor_table left join state_table on state=state.id 
WHERE state_table.state_name <> NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT first_name,last_name, "replace_string" as state_name
FROM doctor_table left join state_table on state=state.id 
WHERE state_table.state_name == NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select for your `IFNULL`

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,
       IFNULL(state_table.state_name,(SELECT some_value FROM some_table WHERE id=some_key))
FROM doctor_table
LEFT JOIN state_table on state=state.id
```

You need to make sure that your sub-select returns exactly 1 value or the whole query will fail.

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd95/1) with the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,
IFNULL(state_table.state_name,(SELECT `name` FROM table WHERE Id='something' LIMIT 1)) as something 
FROM doctor_table left join state_table on state=state.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about any quirks specific to mysql, but in t-sql you can use a nested select statement in ISNULL, but it wouldn't make a particularly efficient query.

You'd get better performance by making an outer join onto your preferred table and then use the column you want as the second parameter in the call to ISNULL.